# Finding Unique Rows that Fail to Join in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, one is called "keywords"; this table simply stores keywords as a unique keyword ID, and the text of the keyword. The other is called "keylinks"; this table stores rows linking a media ID to a keyword ID.

If I had a media item, and I wanted to get all the keywords for that media item, I would use the following code:

```
   SELECT keywords.*, keylinks.*
     FROM keywords
LEFT JOIN keylinks ON (keylinks.keyword_id = keywords.keyword_id)
    WHERE keylinks.media_id = ?
```

What if I wanted to do the opposite?
Instead of getting the keywords that match a media ID, I would like to get the keywords that DON'T match a media ID. How would I do this? I cant simply use `WHERE keylinks.media_id != ?` because that would return thousands of rows of keylink entries that don't relate to that specific media ID, which may in fact be matching keywords.

Comment: so, you want a media_id that doesn't match a keyword, given that you have a keyword?

Comment: I think you guys are a bit confused on what I am trying to ask... I'm not looking for all the keywords for which there are no keylinks... I'm looking for all the keywords for which there are no keylinks matching a specific media ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's at least three means of doing this.  ANSI provides `EXCEPT`, which doesn't appear to be supported by MySQL at this time.

### LEFT JOIN/IS NULL

The placement of criteria with an OUTER JOIN is crucial - if in the WHERE clause, the criteria is applied *after* the JOIN.  If the criteria is in the JOIN, the criteria is applied *before* the JOIN.

```
   SELECT k.*
     FROM KEYWORDS k
LEFT JOIN KEYLINKS kl ON kl.keyword_id = k.keyword_id 
                     AND.media_id = ?
    WHERE keylinks.media_id IS NULL
```

### NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT k.*
  FROM KEYWORDS k
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                     FROM KEYLINKS kl 
                    WHERE kl.keyword_id = k.keyword_id
                      AND kl.media_id = ?)
```

### NOT IN

```
SELECT k.*
  FROM KEYWORDS k
 WHERE k.keyword_id NOT IN (SELECT kl.keyword_id
                              FROM KEYLINKS kl
                             WHERE kl.media_id = ?)
```

### Which Performs Best?

It depends on if the columns compared can be nullable (the value could be `NULL`) or not.

- [If the values are **not** nullable](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/), the `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` is the fastest means ***on MySQL only***.
- [Otherwise, if the columns are nullable -- `NOT EXISTS`/`NOT IN` are the most efficient](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/).

Comment: I think you guys are a bit confused on what I am trying to ask... I'm not looking for all the keywords for which there are no keylinks... I'm looking for all the keywords for which there are no keylinks matching a specific media ID.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT K1.keyword_id 
  FROM keywords AS K1
 WHERE 
   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM keylinks AS K2 
                WHERE K2.keyword_id = K1.keyword_id 
                  AND K2.media_id = %d);
```

This will give you all keywords for which there are no keylinks in the database.

Comment: I think you guys are a bit confused on what I am trying to ask... I'm not looking for all the keywords for which there are no keylinks... I'm looking for all the keywords for which there are no keylinks matching a specific media ID.